# Why do I get a success code when I start a task, but it does nothing?

Tags: c++, windows, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

Please help me to solve a problem. I'm trying to copy a system RegIdleBackup task and launch the copied task. I successfully copied task with ITaskService api, and change some settings in it. And after all i tried to Run this task, and I got return code *S_OK*, but task info didn't changed in Task Scheduler window and backup files didn't update. I can manually run this task from task sheduler and my copied task works good. My problem is with launch method, but i can't find it. Thank you.

Here is my code

```
HRESULT GetTask(ITaskService* pService, const std::wstring& fullTaskName, IRegisteredTask** pTask)
{
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = pFolder->GetTask(SysAllocString(L"RegIdleBackup"), pTask);
    pFolder->Release();
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateTaskCopy(ITaskService* pService, IRegisteredTask* pTask, const std::wstring& fullTaskName)
{
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    pService->Release();

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    ITaskDefinition* pTaskDef = nullptr;
    ITaskSettings* pTaskSettings = nullptr;
    IRegisteredTask* iTask = nullptr;
    hr = pTask->get_Definition(&pTaskDef);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        goto exit;
    hr = pTaskDef->get_Settings(&pTaskSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        goto exit;
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_AllowDemandStart(_variant_t(TRUE));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        goto exit;
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_MultipleInstances(TASK_INSTANCES_PARALLEL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        goto exit;

    hr = pTaskDef->put_Settings(pTaskSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        goto exit;
    pTaskSettings->Release();
    pTaskSettings = nullptr;

    hr = pFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), 0);
    hr = pFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()),
        pTaskDef,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(),
        TASK_LOGON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &iTask);

exit:
    if (pTaskSettings)
        pTaskSettings->Release();
    if (iTask)
        iTask->Release();
    if (pTaskDef)
        pTaskDef->Release();
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CopyTask(const std::wstring& fullTaskName, const std::wstring& copyName)
{
    ITaskService* pService = nullptr;
    IRegisteredTask* pTask = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = GetTask(pService, fullTaskName, &pTask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        goto exit;

    hr = CreateTaskCopy(pService, pTask, copyName);

exit:
    if(pService)
        pService->Release();
    if (pTask)
        pTask->Release();
    return hr;
}

HRESULT StartTask(const std::wstring& fullTaskName)
{
    ITaskService* pService = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pService->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    IRegisteredTask* pTask = nullptr;
    pFolder->GetTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), &pTask);
    pFolder->Release();

    IRunningTask* pRunningTask = nullptr;
    hr = pTask->RunEx(_variant_t(),0,0, _bstr_t(L"S-1-5-18"), &pRunningTask);
    pTask->Release();

    return hr;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = CopyTask(L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\RegIdleBackup", L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\MyTask");
    hr = StartTask(L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\MyTask");

    CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today morning I tried to run task with replacing launch trigger, and same time fixed some task settings. And all worked good, and after all I started to test my program on Win 7 and all were great, but on Win10 i got some interesting issue, task created with another last launch time (on Win7 field empty, on Win 10 message - "Task never launched before") and i tried to use IRegisteredTask::Run method, and it's worked! I tested on other OSes and run method working. I paste my code sample, maybe it canbe usefull for somebody.

```
HRESULT GetTaskDefinition(ITaskService* pService, const std::wstring& fullTaskName, ITaskDefinition** pTask)
{
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    IRegisteredTask* pRegTask = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = pFolder->GetTask(SysAllocString(L"RegIdleBackup"), &pRegTask);
    pFolder->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = pRegTask->get_Definition(pTask);
    return hr;
}

HRESULT ChangeTaskSettings(ITaskDefinition* pTaskDef)
 {
    ITaskSettings* pTaskSettings = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pTaskDef->get_Settings(&pTaskSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_AllowDemandStart(VARIANT_TRUE);
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_MultipleInstances(TASK_INSTANCES_PARALLEL);
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_RunOnlyIfIdle(VARIANT_FALSE);
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_StartWhenAvailable(VARIANT_TRUE);
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_StopIfGoingOnBatteries(VARIANT_FALSE);
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_Enabled(VARIANT_FALSE);
    hr = pTaskSettings->put_DisallowStartIfOnBatteries(VARIANT_FALSE);
    hr = pTaskDef->put_Settings(pTaskSettings);
    pTaskSettings->Release();
    return hr;
}

FILETIME AddSecondsToFIleTime(FILETIME ft, unsigned seconds)
{
    FILETIME res;
#define _SECONDS ((__int64) 10000000) //100 ns intervals in second
    ULONGLONG tmp = (static_cast<ULONGLONG>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime + seconds*_SECONDS;
    res.dwLowDateTime = static_cast<DWORD>(tmp & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    res.dwHighDateTime = static_cast<DWORD>(tmp >> 32);
    return res;
}

std::wstring GetTaskLaunchTimeWstring(SYSTEMTIME st, unsigned wait_interval)
{
    FILETIME ft;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
    ft = AddSecondsToFIleTime(ft, wait_interval);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << st.wYear << "-" << 
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << st.wMonth << "-" << 
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << st.wDay << "T" <<
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << st.wHour << ":" <<
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << st.wMinute << ":" << 
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << st.wSecond;
    std::string str = ss.str();
    return std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
}

HRESULT ChangeTaskTriggers(ITaskDefinition* pTaskDef, const std::wstring& LaunchTimeStr)
 {
    ITriggerCollection* pTriggersCollection = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pTaskDef->get_Triggers(&pTriggersCollection);
    hr = pTriggersCollection->Clear();

    ITrigger* pTrigger = nullptr;
    hr = pTriggersCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME, &pTrigger);
    pTriggersCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    ITimeTrigger* pTimeTrigger = nullptr;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface(IID_ITimeTrigger, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pTimeTrigger));
    pTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_Id(_bstr_t(L"Trigger"));
    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_Enabled(VARIANT_TRUE);
    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_StartBoundary(_bstr_t(LaunchTimeStr.c_str()));
    pTimeTrigger->Release();

    return hr;
 }

HRESULT RegisterTask(ITaskService* pService, ITaskDefinition* pTaskDef, const std::wstring& fullTaskName)
{
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);

    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;


    IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTAsk = nullptr;
    hr = pFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), 0);
    hr = pFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()),
        pTaskDef,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(),
        TASK_LOGON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTAsk);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pRegisteredTAsk->put_Enabled(VARIANT_TRUE);
        pRegisteredTAsk->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateModifiedTaskCopy(const std::wstring& fullTaskName, const std::wstring& copyName, unsigned seconds_to_start)
{
    ITaskService* pService = nullptr;
    ITaskDefinition* pTaskDef = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = GetTaskDefinition(pService, fullTaskName, &pTaskDef);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pService->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    hr = ChangeTaskSettings(pTaskDef);

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);
    const std::wstring launchStr = GetTaskLaunchTimeWstring(st, seconds_to_start);
    hr = ChangeTaskTriggers(pTaskDef, launchStr);
    hr = RegisterTask(pService, pTaskDef, copyName);

    pTaskDef->Release();
    pService->Release();

    return hr;
}

HRESULT WaitUntilTaskCompleted(const std::wstring& fullTaskName, unsigned taskTimeout, unsigned maxWaitTime)
{
    ITaskService* pService = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pService->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    IRegisteredTask* pTask = nullptr;
    hr = pFolder->GetTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), &pTask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pFolder->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    DATE lastRun;
    unsigned tries = 0;
    do 
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        hr = pTask->get_LastRunTime(&lastRun);
        tries++;
        if (tries > maxWaitTime)
            break;
    } while (hr == SCHED_S_TASK_HAS_NOT_RUN);

    return tries > maxWaitTime? SCHED_E_INVALID_TASK :S_OK;
}

HRESULT DeleteTask(const std::wstring& fullTaskName)
{
    ITaskService* pService = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pService->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = pFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), 0);
    pFolder->Release();

    return hr;
}

HRESULT RunTask(const std::wstring& fullTaskName)
{
    ITaskService* pService = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pService->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    const std::wstring taskFolder = fullTaskName.substr(0, fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\'));
    const std::wstring taskName = fullTaskName.substr(fullTaskName.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    ITaskFolder* pFolder = nullptr;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(taskFolder.c_str()), &pFolder);
    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    IRegisteredTask* pTask = nullptr;
    hr = pFolder->GetTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), &pTask);
    pFolder->Release();

    IRunningTask* pRunTask = nullptr;
    pTask->Run(_variant_t(), &pRunTask);
    pTask->Release();
    pRunTask->Release();

    return hr;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }
    const unsigned seconds_to_start = 30;
    hr = CreateModifiedTaskCopy(L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\RegIdleBackup", L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\MyTask", seconds_to_start);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }
    RunTask(L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\MyTask");
    hr = WaitUntilTaskCompleted(L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\MyTask", seconds_to_start, seconds_to_start * 4);

    hr = DeleteTask(L"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Registry\\MyTask");

    CoUninitialize();

    printf("All ok!\r\n");
    return hr;
}
```